# I'm getting these static after i scale my mesh - Is this a bug?

Tags: transforms

My mesh was very small (.002 on scale ).  This was exported from Zbrush.

Anyway, I made it normal size and now I'm getting this static thing on my mesh.  This only happens AFTER I scale it.  Do you know what's wrong?

[image]

[image]

There are no modifiers applied.

Comment: Probably not. May need the normals correcting or back face culling disabled. Please share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there so that we can have a look.

Comment: Looks like it's a clipping issue.  Updated my question.

Comment: You said that you scaled your object to increase its size. Did you apply the scale (Ctrl-A > Scale) in Object mode after you'd scaled it? - That can sometimes cause problems.

Comment: Yes I did.  It did not fix the issue.  I don't know how many people here export from Zbrush on default settings, but this issue should happen quite often if you do.  Zbrush on average makes your mesh .002 in blender size.  ( Mine is in meters maybe that's why).  I need to always scale up.  However, this is the first time I've had this issue.

Answer (score 1):

So after much digging (thanks to other users experiencing same problem), I was able to remove these after changing my Clip Start to a higher value.  Because Zbrush exports are super tiny in Blender for some reason, I had to zoom in and increase the clipping value to .0001 from .00001

Anyway, whenever you see this issue, just change your clip start to a higher value, it fixes the problem.  I don't know enough about Blender to believe if this is a bug with the clipping.

[image]